# npgsql postgresql functions to use in LINQ

Tags: entity-framework, linq, postgresql, npgsql, dotconnect

Is there anything on npgsql similar to the SqlFunctions class, or the PgSqlFunctions available on dotConnect?

I've been trying to create a dynamic sql expression using LINQ, but things like ToString or PadLeft can't be processed by LINQ.

I really need to be able to cast from datetime to string, among others.

Comment: Weirdly enough I don't remember this feature being requested before... Can you please open an issue on https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql, and include the specific functions you're missing?